# fade in when hover and fadeout when mouse goes away

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote this code that fades in a non displaying div but i don´t really know how to fadeout the div again when the mouse goes away. any suggestions?

```
$(document).ready(
        function(){
        $("#crep").hover(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".wrapper2 img, #galerie, #ueber, #djs").invisible();
            $(".carta ,#crepes, #crepes2").fadeIn();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Here lie your answer : https://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/

Comment: use a callback function

Comment: Consider that this is also easily achieved using CSS3 transitions, by setting e.g. `#fadingThingy { opacity: 0; transition: opacity 500ms }` and `#fadingThingy.shown { opacity: 1 }`, then using Javascript to toggle the `shown` CSS class.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**.hover**](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) which is used to

> Bind one or two handlers to the matched elements, to be executed when
>   the mouse pointer enters and leaves the elements.
>
> The .hover() method binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave
>   events. You can use it to simply apply behavior to an element during
>   the time the mouse is within the element.
>
> Eg: $( selector ).hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )

### JS:

```
$("#crep").hover(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".wrapper2 img, #galerie, #ueber, #djs").invisible();
            $(".carta ,#crepes, #crepes2").fadeIn();       
         }, function(){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".carta ,#crepes, #crepes2").fadeOut();
    });
```

Comment: the only problem is that the shown div (a slidesdown menu) shouldnt disappear when i go over the menu

Comment: on hover the menu, show the required div ? Simple. :)

Answer (score 0):

[.hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) can have two functions... one for `mouseenter` the other for `mouseleave`.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/92HR8/)

```
$(document).ready(
  function () {
    $("#crep").hover(
      function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //$(".wrapper2 img, #galerie, #ueber, #djs").invisible(); //what does invisible do ??
        $(".carta ,#crepes, #crepes2").stop().fadeIn();
      },
      function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //$(".wrapper2 img, #galerie, #ueber, #djs").invisible(); //what does invisible do ??
        $(".carta ,#crepes, #crepes2").stop().fadeOut();
      }   
    );
});
```

Comment: invisibile is a function that i wrote to hidde some element but with visibility: hidden..

the code works thanks... the only problem is that the shown div (a slidesdown menu) shouldnt disappear when i go over the menu